# How to delete non working excel file after checking with python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to open an Excel file using load_workbook, and sometimes there can be issues with this file, resulting in a badzipfile error. If I encounter this error while opening the Excel file, I attempt to remove the existing file and then try to open a new Excel file with the same name. However, I'm receiving the following logs:

**Failed with: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
**

How can I solve this problem ? I want to delete file which has issue

```
    def is_excel_file_valid(self):
        name = self.extract_excel_file_name_from_txt(excel_file_name)
        self.file_name = name
        print(self.file_name)
        self.wb = ""
        try:

            self.wb = load_workbook(filename=self.file_name)
            if self.today in self.wb.sheetnames:
                print("Excel file working correctly")
            else:
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
                # writer.self.wb = self.wb
                df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.title)
                df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=self.today)
                writer.close()
        except BadZipfile:
           
            archive = ZipFile(name, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
            archive.close()

            if os.path.exists(name):  # Dosya varsa
                print("Dosya var")
                try:
                    os.remove(name)  # Dosyayı sil
                    print(f"{name} dosyası başarıyla silindi.")
                    self.write_name_to_txt_file(excel_file_name, name)
                    self.update_day()
                    self.update_excel_file_name()
                    self.wb = load_workbook(filename=self.file_name)
                except OSError as e:  # name the Exception `e`
                    print( "Failed with:", e.strerror)  # look what it says
```

I also try with this:

```
  with load_workbook(filename=self.file_name) as self.wb:
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, please mark it as accepted. If not please let me know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You never close the `self.wb`.
I would close it immediately as that is probably the best way since you never use it again. Also use the pd.ExcelWriter as context manager, so that the file properly closes when an Exception occurs.

```py
try:
    self.wb = load_workbook(filename=self.file_name)
    workbook_ok = self.today in self.wb.sheetnames
    self.wb.close()
    if workbook_ok :
        print("Excel file working correctly")
    else:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(self.file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
            df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.title)
            df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=self.today)
except BadZipfile:
    ...
```

I don't quite understand why you would open the file with `ZipFile` only to close it again immediately.

The zipfile is handled by openpyxl when you open the workbook, so closing the workbook also closes the zip handle.